# Assistance with MSSQL query to group data

Tags: sql-server

**SAMPLE DATA HAS BEEN UPDATED - I jumped the gun on posting data before it was confirmed**

Using **SQL Server**, I have the following data being returned:

```
select id, dateofservice, first, second, third, fourth, fn, ln
from servicesTbl
```

Sample data:

```
id  dateofservice   first   second  third   fourth  fn      ln      
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2/01/2013       Y       N       N       Y       John    Doe    
2   2/01/2013       N       N       Y       Y       Sue     Fisher    
2   2/01/2013       Y       N       N       N       Sue     Fisher    
3   2/01/2013       Y       N       N       Y       Daivd   Smith    
3   2/01/2013       N       N       Y       N       Daivd   Smith       
4   2/01/2013       N       N       N       N       Bob     Denver
```

I need to know how to write my query so that Sue Fisher's and David Smith's records are all on one line meaning the output should look like:

```
1   2/01/2013       Y       N       N       Y       John    Doe    
2   2/01/2013       Y       N       Y       Y       Sue     Fisher    
3   2/01/2013       Y       N       Y       Y       Daivd   Smith       
4   2/01/2013       N       N       N       N       Bob     Denver
```

This query isn't working for me and I'm not sure what to do to get the output in the format I'd like.

```
select id, dateofservice, first, second, third, fourth, fn, ln    
from servicesTbl    
group by ln
```

**SAMPLE DATA HAS BEEN UPDATED - I jumped the gun on posting data before it was confirmed**

Comment: What output are you expecting for the other columns (e.g. first, second, third)?  Should these be summed?

Comment: Put max round each column after dateofservice, e.g. max (first), etc.

Comment: @ChrisC Not sumed, the 1 and 0 are yes/no values.  To get the data for Sue Fisher the way it is, her record was updated at two different times and for some reason now has to entries in teh database (that is a separate issue we are working on).  I just need Sue Fisher's record to be on one line instead of the two so the values should be merged, not summed.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    dateofservice, 
    (CASE WHEN SUM(first) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS first, 
    (CASE WHEN SUM(second) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS second, 
    (CASE WHEN SUM(third) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS third, 
    (CASE WHEN SUM(fourth) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fourth, 
    fn, 
    ln 
    OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM servicesTbl
```

This would probably work too, thinking about it and it's a little more succinct:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    dateofservice, 
    MAX(first) AS first, 
    MAX(second) AS second, 
    MAX(third) AS third, 
    MAX(fourth) AS fourth, 
    fn, 
    ln 
    OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM servicesTbl
```

The usual way to do this in something like MySQL would be:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    dateofservice, 
    MAX(first) AS first, 
    MAX(second) AS second,
    MAX(third) AS third,
    MAX(fourth) AS fourth,
    fn, 
    ln
FROM servicesTbl
GROUP BY id
```

... but I think I'm right in saying MSSQL will complain about fn, ln not being aggregate functions or not being in the GROUP BY clause: using the OVER PARTITION method above should resolve this.

Note, this is untested as I don't have MSSQL to hand, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2005, not MySQL.

Comment: SAMPLE DATA HAS BEEN UPDATED - I jumped the gun on posting data before it was confirmed

Comment: I see that, that's why I said "... but I think I'm right in saying MSSQL will complain about..." etc.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I've been flamed for not including the DB I'm using so just wanted to make sure it was clarified.  Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateofservice,111) as Dateofservice,
 MAX(first) as first ,
 MAX(second) as second,
 MAX(third) as third,
 MAX(fourth) as fourth, fn, ln from dbo.ttest
group by id,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Dateofservice,111),fn, ln
```

I have named the table as tttest you can use your table name. Plus i have used a random date format change it to suit yourself.

Comment: SAMPLE DATA HAS BEEN UPDATED - I jumped the gun on posting data before it was confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Using CF, I was able to perform a group by and then a query

```
<table>
    <cfoutput query='rsData' group="id">
        <cfoutput>
            <tr>
                <td>#dateformat(dateofservice,'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
                <td>#first#</td>
                <td>#second#</td>
                <td>#third#</td>
                <td>#fourth#</td>
                <td>#fn#</td>
                <td>#ln#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
```